# Ubuntu 18. How to format USB from file explorer

Tags: 18.04

Ubuntu had the crazy idea of removing the right click from laptops (in the path), I used to format usb drives with a right click + format. How can I format usbs in ubuntu 18? is there a fast and easy way?

Comment: Please clarify your details, you mention Ubuntu 18 (desktop & server releases use a *yy.mm* format, only specialist releases use *yy* and they don't have GUI so right-click makes no sense).  You also tagged an EOL release.

Comment: I do not understand "*Ubuntu had the crazy idea of removing the right click from laptops*" - right-click on my system works properly. Do you not have a "disks" application? It's part of the normal install.

Comment: The right click is still there. Try the disks app like user535733 suggested. If you can't format with that than do a little more trouble shooting to your system for this issue and see what you can find out.